# I need to use Directory.GetFiles but with a few more conditions

Tags: vb.net

Here's an example. Lets say I have two files in a directory:

1. Filename_v1.pdf
2. Filename_v1_ABC.pdf

Here's some code:

```
Dim StorageRoot = "SomePath"
Dim RootName = "Filename"
Dim Suffix = "_v"
Dim matchingFiles as string()

matchingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(StorageRoot, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName.ToString) + "*.*")
```

This returns both files mentioned above, but I need to only match files where the first `*` in `*.*` if it is numeric. So I need it to ignore a file if it has anything other than a number after the `Suffix`.

---- Edit ----

It chewed some of my example. Here's some pseudo code:

```
 matchingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(StorageRoot, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName.ToString) + "onlyifitisnumeric.*")
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use `Directory.GetFiles` as you do now and then further filtrate using `Linq` and 'Regular Expression'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use [Regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order take only those file whose name is matching the pattern you want to have and filter the result from `GetDirectory`. The pattern in this case could be:

```
.*_v[0-9]\.pdf
```

meaning

```
.*_v  <- all symbols followed by "_v"
[0-9] <- followed by a number
\.pdf  <- followed by ".pdf"
```

The pattern can also use the [`\d` character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that means `Matches any decimal digit.` and makes the pattern shorter:

```
.*_v\d\.pdf
```

And the code can look like this:

```
dim path = "d:\\temp\\xml\\"
dim files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf")

Dim rx = new Regex(".*_v\d\.pdf") ' or Dim rx = new Regex(".*_v[0-9]\.pdf")

for each file in files
    if rx.IsMatch(file) then
        ' do something with the file
        Console.WriteLine(file)
    end if
next file
```

If you want your code to be succinct then you could use [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx):

```
dim path = "d:\\temp\\xml\\"
dim files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*")

Dim rx = new Regex(".*\d\.pdf") ' or Dim rx = new Regex(".*[0-9]\.pdf")

dim filteredFiles = files.Where(function(file) rx.IsMatch(file))
```

Comment: ...are you sure about `.pdf` matches `.pdf`? And _nothing else_? ;)

Comment: fixed. thanks! :) it has worked even when the `.` was not escaped.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.IO

 [...]
        Dim rx As New Regex("^filename_v\d$")
        Dim f = (From fItem As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("PathToFiles")
                 Where rx.IsMatch(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fItem))
                 Select fItem).ToArray
        ' Test Output
        MessageBox.Show(String.Join(vbCrLf, f))
```

Use `Regex("^filename_v\d+$")` to match numbers of any length.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do. First Get files with `_v*_*`, which possible using regular wildcards. Then, apply additional pattern you need to get the subset of files.

```
Dim files As IEnumerable(Of String) = _
Directory.GetFiles("your path", "your initial optional wildcard").Where(Function(f) Regex.IsMatch(f, "<your pattern>"))
```